# how to redirect usb DVD burning from Ubuntu 12.04 to Windows 7

Tags: 12.04, remote-desktop, burning

I have a home Ubuntu 12.04.4 64bit machine equipped with an external CD/DVD writer drive attached via USB port.

And in my office I have a Windows 7 64bit machine.

I want to redirect my usb DVD drive via remote desktop or any kind of remote connection so that I can see my drive as if it's connected directly to remote server.

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect your Ubuntu machine remotely then you can check whether your optical drive is presented/connected or not by:

`ls /dev/sr0`

If there are more than one of them and/or it has a different number then you can find it in

`grep "dvd" /var/log/dmesg`

EDIT:
when you need to mount your CD/DVD remotely you can do `mount` for it on remote machine and then mount the remote directory to your local file system. One of the method I would chose first is `sshfs`

Comment: thanks but this is far away from my question. I need to mount cd remotely (like usb redirection)

Comment: I added edition to my answer.